# How can I completely disable all caching in Safari 4?

Tags: macos, safari

I want Safari to *always* fetch resources, regardless of how old they are, rather than the current behaviour. So, it should never heed the HTTP headers or meta tags that dictate caching.

It would be sufficient for this to apply to a limited set of sites.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Any particular reason you're still using Safari 4?

Comment: No clue, but that's the version that comes up in the about box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable the Developer menu (`Safari, Preferences, Advanced, Show Develop menu in menu bar`) and select `Disable Caches` there.

I'm using Safari 5, but according to [here](http://mac.elated.com/2008/05/22/web-developer-features-in-safari/) this menu is present in Safari since at least 3.0